# Disable all click/keyup events until ajax call has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click, keyup

How would you disable all links from being able to be triggered until an ajax call has finished?

I need this to happen on both `.(click)` events and `.on('keyup')` triggers.

So pretty much what I want is;

– Ajax link is triggered (by either a click or keyup)

– Ajax call runs (and whilst is running – all links are disabled)

– Ajax call finishes and links are reenabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can add spinner and show the spinner in foreground until yours ajax request is successful. Here is a sample code. Here is an example.

```
function OnAjaxStart(ajaxContext) {
$("#spinner").show();
$("a").unbind("click");
$("a").unbind("keyup");
}

function OnAjaxComplete(ajaxContext) {
$("#spinner").hide();
}


function DisplayDataById(actionUrl, data) {
OnAjaxStart();

var request = $.ajax({
url: actionUrl,
data: { data: data},
cache: false
});

request.done(function (data) {
$('#' + divName).empty().html(data);
OnAjaxComplete();
});
}
```

Here is the spinner HTML:

```
<div id="spinner" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
  top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
  opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70); display: none">
  <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
    Please wait ...<img src="@Url.Content("~=""/images/loading-image.gif")" alt="Loading">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but the question was to disable all links during an ajax request (and until all animations in the call have finished) - then reenabling all links once the call has completed. Some of my links are being triggered by `on.('keyup')` events so if someone was to press a key multiple times, there is the chance that my layout will break due to animations being run. Thanks for the answer though. @Bhasyakarulu Kottakota

Comment: Try adding unbind to OnAjaxStart method.

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks for your help, I'd up vote your answer but I need 4 more points!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  CSS */
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

On ajax call use this

```
overlay = $("<div id='overlay'></div>").prependTo('body');
    $(document).on("keydown",function(objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
        objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
   });
```

On finish of ajax call use this

```
overlay.remove();
$(document).off("keydown");
```

Comment: This works for clicks but not `.on('keyup')` triggers.

Comment: We can disable tab key using jquery. Use it to remove keyup.